Is 'Round to Even' Applied Differently in Chemistry?
In my high school chemistry class, my teacher insists that the "round to even" rule means rounding to the nearest even number whenever the next digit is 5, regardless of any digits that follow. For example, she teaches that 2.59 rounded to the nearest whole number should be 2, claiming that rounding 2.59 to 3 would be "chain rounding" because it considers digits beyond the tenths place.
From my understanding, "round to even" should only apply when the number is exactly halfway between two options (like 2.5 or 3.5), and not when there are additional digits. When I explained this, my teacher said, "this is what we do in honors chemistry."
Is there a different rounding convention in chemistry that justifies this approach, or is this a misunderstanding of the "round to even" rule?

You ask two different questions: round to even and round to whole number. 2.5 or 2.59, rounded to whole number is 3, but 2.5, 2.59, or even 2.999990 rounded to nearest even number is 2.

@DrMoishePippik Round to even is a specific method for rounding numbers. It states that when a number is exactly halfway between two integers, it rounds to the nearest even number. For example, 2.5, using the round-to-even rule to round to the nearest whole number, would round to 2. However, 2.59 would round to 3 because it's closer to 3 than to 2, and the "round to even" rule wouldn't apply since it's not exactly halfway. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding

Rounding is a mathematical artifact. In experimental science data is presented to the first or possibly the second insignificant or variable figure and when feasible with a standard deviation. Additional digits generated by computer are meaningless and should be ignored. An estimated digit should not perturb a precise digit. Rounding should not even be taught; the time much better spent on teaching how to measure properly and simple statistics.

https://www.chemteam.info/SigFigs/Rounding.html will help a lot

Round to even is not limited to closest even integers, but applicable also to the closest even number in the upper order,  roung e.g. n.nn45 ->o n.nn4, or 165 -> 160.  It is applied when registered/collected data are of lower precision than measured data, but there is the need to avoid rounding statistical bias, and 5 is by the standard way rounded always  up. Typical application is meteorology/climatology.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/38227/how-to-round-significant-figures-correctly

This question later cross-posted to Mathematics SE, namely Are there different conventions for 'rounding to even'?
